# NPN_MemAlloc after NPN_MemFree screws the returning data to Google Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, free, allocation, npapi

I've finished my NPAPI plug-in and it works great in Google Chrome but there's a strange problem. The problem is that I've coded a method in the plug-in that returns a string to the browser. In order to do so, you have to allocate a memory in the browser and copy the resulting string to it. Something like:

```
bool
ScriptablePluginObject::Invoke(NPIdentifier name, const NPVariant *args,
                               uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result)
{
    if (name == sMethod_id) {
  ...

  //free the memory if it is already allocated
  if (m_pPtr) NPN_MemFree(m_pPtr);

  //allocate the string in the browser memory
  m_pPtr = (char*)NPN_MemAlloc(size+1);
  SecureZeroMemory(m_pPtr, size+1);
  memcpy(m_pATR, string, size);

  //send result to browser
  STRINGZ_TO_NPVARIANT(m_pPtr, *result);

  return true;
 }
  ...

}
```

Note that 'm_pPtr' is a data member of the class and is initialized to NULL upon construction. The problem occurs when I call this method twice from Google Chrome. The first time it works great. From the second time and so on, it returns a garbage value displayed 'X' in the browser. I've tested the same plug-in in Firefox and it works fine and returns the correct value no matter how many times I call the method. But when I close the page which loaded the plug-in, then Firefox crashes.

Any pointers to what happens in this strange situation is appreciated. I'm working on it and will update the thread once I reach any useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the following line:

```
if (m_pPtr) NPN_MemFree(m_pPtr);
```

You are returning the string to the script and the caller (in this case the browsers JavaScript engine) owns it.

If you free it this leads to [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as the memory could still be in use or already re-used or freed by the browser.

Comment: This is definitely the problem.  For more info, read up on Memory Management in NPAPI: http://colonelpanic.net/2009/12/memory-management-in-npapi/